# Volley StringRequest getParams() does not call

Tags: android, post, android-volley

I'm trying to use `StringRequest` with volley and surprisingly the `getParams()` method never called in `POST` request. In my other projects It work fine but I cant figure It out what is the matter with this one!

Below is my code :

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, SystemConfigs.getNewPosts(context), new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        boolean result = Boolean.parseBoolean(response);
        if (result) {
            publishProgressState(3);
            if (postCount > currentDownloaded) {
                getNewPosts(postsList);
            } else {
                publishProgressState(5);
                downloaded = 0;
                currentDownloaded = 0;
                ds.openReadable();
                String list = ds.getPostsString();
                ds.close();
                getUpdatedPosts(list);

            }
        } else {
            publishProgressState(-1);
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        publishProgressState(-1);
    }
}) {

    @Override
    protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String jsonString = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            boolean result = savePosts(jsonString, true);
            return Response.success(result + "", HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("page", (++downloaded) + "");
        headers.put("list", list == null ? "" : list);

        return headers;
    }

};
request.setRetryPolicy(new

DefaultRetryPolicy(5000,
                   DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                   DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT)

);

appSingleton.getRequestQueue().add(request);
```

Accidently I found out that If I clear the volley cache, `getParams()` method called. But what If I want to call a paged service like above and I want to send page numbers by post request?

Answer (score 0):

What does SystemConfigs.getNewPosts(context) returns? Does it return correct URL for the String request?

Comment: yes it returns the service URL. `onResponse` and `parseNetwrokResponse` called correctly so the URL is correct